# How to check if a git repo was updated without using a git command

Tags: python, git

TL;DR
I would like to be able to check if a git repo (located on a shared network) was updated without using a git command. I was thinking checking one of the files located in the .git folder to do so, but I can't find the best file to check. Anyone have a suggestion on how to achieve this?

Why:
The reason why I need to do this is because I have many git repos located on a shared drive. From a python application I built, I synchronize the content of some of these git repo on a local drive on a lot of workstation and render nodes.

I don't want to use git because the git server is not powerful enough to support the amount of requests of all the computers in the studio would need to perform constantly.

This is why I ended up with the solution of putting the repos on the network server and syncing the repo content on a local cache on each computer using rsync

That works fine, but the as time goes by, the repos are getting larger and the rsync is taking too much time to perform. So I would like to be have to (ideally) check one file that would tell me if the local copy is out of sync with the network copy and perform the rsync only when they are out of sync.

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you use the git command? You can check for the last update without having to connect to the git server

Comment: you could just hash the files and compare the hashes if you want to check if they are out of sync without using a ton of bandwidth

Comment: if you want to check if "working directory" was updated outside of git, then use `git status`

Comment: If you have to handle performance issues because of high load/traffic (which triggered this question, if I understood it correctly), optimization and tuning can only go so far. Sooner or later, you'll have to scale out. Once you have to do that, an approach inspired by [GitHub's DGit](http://githubengineering.com/introducing-dgit/) (which _does_ use Git protocols for syncing, though maybe not Git CLI _commands_) might actually be easier to handle and could perform better than doing lower-level stuff on the file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `.git/FETCH_HEAD` for the time stamp and the content.

Every time you fetch content its updating the content and the modification time of the file.

Comment: This looks like it would be the right solution for my case after doing a few test in python.
Thanks

Comment: Coo. glad to help.